# PyQT4: Error while using setQuery() in QSqlQueryModel()

Tags: sql-server, pyqt4, qsqlquery

When I enter the query in setQuery in the following way, I get no error:

```
    projectModel = QSqlQueryModel() 
    projectModel.setQuery("Select * from xyz")
```

But when I do the exact same thing in the following way, I get an error:

```
    query5 = QSqlQuery ()
    projectModel = QSqlQueryModel() 
    query5.prepare ("Select * from xyz")
    projectModel.setQuery(query5)
```

Why is it so? How do I resolve this error? The error is:

```
<PyQt4.QtSql.QSqlError object at 0x0000000003B6A5F8>
```

Comment: `print(sqlerror.text())`.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro I did try to get the error and this is the error message I got:
<PyQt4.QtSql.QSqlError object at 0x0000000003B6A5F8>

The application doesn't give a error otherwise, just doesn't work at all

Comment: That is clearly **not** an error message. Please print the text of the error object, as I suggested.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro: I added the following lines of code: 
a=QSqlError()
 print(a.text())
And I got just a blank space as output

Comment: `print(projectModel.lastError().text())` or `print(query5.lastError().text())` or `print(some_other_error_object.text())`.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro the error message pointed at an issue in my query. On modifying the query, it works as expected. Thanks for all your help!